# Why my ajax cannot retrieve ajax code

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i got some problem dealing with json, please help me T.T
**my ajax**

```
//submit the form
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp){
          alert(resp);      
          $('#' + thediv).html(resp);
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(thrownError);
      }    
});
```

it just alert(200) and then alert(undefine)

when i change datatype to html, all data can b retrieve 
but the json file is print in pages, 
is this extension problem?

**my Json text**

```
{ 
  "menu": "File", 
  "commands": [ 
      {
          "title": "New", 
          "action":"CreateDoc"
      }, 
      {
          "title": "Open", 
          "action": "OpenDoc"
      }, 
      {
          "title": "Close",
          "action": "CloseDoc"
      }
   ] 
}
```

Comment: What Content-Type is the server is sending?  It should be application/json.  You can determine the current value from Firebug or curl, among other ways.

Answer (score -1):

if you're connecting to asp.net MVC or WCF, perhaps add this line to your ajax call

```
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: `contentType` is the content type you're passing *to* the server.  The type of the data returned by `serialize` is *not* JSON.

Comment: so i have to format my post data into json code, and then then pass in data..
BTW,i forgot to mention that i am using php to do json-ajax thing.

Comment: but jquery website state that:
"dataTypeString
Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)

The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."